# Extract Assets with CUSTOM Size, Format and quality?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I have a 1920x1080 PSD with many layers (close to a 100) of emeded assets that I need to extract at 66.67% (scaling down to a standard 1280x720).

Is there a way to add a custom size on export? (all is offered is the 0.25x, 0.33x, 0.5, etc...)

In addition! Is there a way to add JPEG (quality 75%) AND PNG (with Transparency) all in the export? Right now it requires to add those setting to export file  individually. Seems to defeat the whole purpose. No?

Am I missing a settings window somewhere?

This is a HUGE time saver IF we can add custom settings.

Thanks for an insight, or work arounds.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't save a copy of the PSD at 66.67% and export at full size?

Comment: How are you "exporting"? The Export command doesn't really offer assent exporting. Are you Using Save for Web? Are you using Generator??

Answer (score 1):

Ah. Good points. Okay. So if I understand correctly you want to en-masse for all layers do:

1. Scale to a custom size
2. Add 2 formats

When you invoke Extract Assets from File > Extract Assets. Is this correct? If so, there is no way to do it within Extract Assets dialog right now :(

You can however set custom size with Generator for all assets using the default layer. Create a new layer and ensure it is the top most layer and use this as the layer name:
`default 66.67%`

(More info on [layer syntax spec](https://github.com/adobe-photoshop/generator-assets/wiki/Generate-Web-Assets-Functional-Spec))

I think it is fair to ensure we offer default asset export options and we need to offer this in the future to ensure the en-masse export as you mention. I will add it to our list of things to consider for the future!

-Divya, Product Manager @ Adobe overseeing the Extract Assets dialog

Comment: Maybe an action + Generator would do the trick? At least that way it can be automated. Can even include a history snapshot initially, then return to that state when done.